# Understanding this illustration for the YOLO network

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

Below is an image of the [YOLO network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640) [image: YOLO network] for object detection. The first layer says `Conv. Layer 7x7x64-s-2`. To the best of my knowledge, it means a convolution layer using a kernel of size `4x4` with 64 output channels and stride 2. But the picture shows 192
output channels at this layer. Am I understanding something wrong or is it a typo in the paper? The second layer has the same porblem while the others don't.

Answer (score -2):

We get 64 output channels per each input channel in the image. Since each image is a colored one, it has 3 channels corresponding to red, green, and blue. Hence we get 64 x 3 = 192 output channels.

Comment: But this doesn't explain the following layers